# Laravel 5: Collective html not working (localhost)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1, laravel-form

I was trying to install laravel Collective form class as instructed in http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html. I added the lines in provider and alias arrays. But it still returning error 'FatalErrorException in 35d2ebae68816953807290e20156144f line 7:
Class 'HTML' not found'

[full error](http://jpst.it/CEsM)

My installation commands- 
[image]

My [Composer.json](http://jpst.it/CEsV) file

My [config->app.php](http://jpst.it/CEt4) file

Comment: Are you using uppercased name, `HTML`? Try with `Html`. I did this mistake a few times.

Comment: I was indeed! Thanks

Comment: Please don't post terminal input and output as image because it's not ideal.

Comment: Sorry, won't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Html
```

instead of:

```
HTML
```